Not passing correct argument through CreateThread
I was trying to create a function in C which would let me pass a character as its argument when using the CreateThread function.
It works for the most part, the thread is created and prints a character. The problem is, it many of the threads don't print the character they are supposed to print, and instead print the last one. I assume it has something to do with how the character is passed on to the function, or perhaps the synchronization.
Here is the code:
#define LETTERS "abcdefghij"

DWORD WINAPI threadFunc(LPVOID param) {
    HANDLE sem = OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, (LPCWSTR)"sem");
    PCHAR name;
    name= (PCHAR)param;
    printf("I'm a thread: %c\n", *name);
    fflush(stdout);
    ReleaseSemaphore(sem, 1, NULL);
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    DWORD(*f)(LPVOID);
    f = threadFunc;

    HANDLE sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 10, (LPCWSTR)"sem");

    int i;
    DWORD name;
    CHAR nameOfThread;
    for (i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
        nameOfThread= LETTERS[i];
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, f, &nameOfThread, 0, &name);
    }

    for (i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
        WaitForSingleObject(sem, INFINITE);
    }
    printf("I'm the process\n");
} 

And here are the results of executing it:
I'm a thread: g
I'm a thread: h
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: j
I'm the process

Any help would be appreciated.

All of your casts are wrong. That's why you shouldn't use casts, unless you clearly understand why they are necessary. Use the correct types instead.

You are using the semaphore all wrong. First off, don't give it a name if it's not being used across process boundaries. You could just pass the open handle from main() into each thread instead. Also, you need to actually wait on an open semaphore handle ie with WaitForSingleObject() before you can call ReleaseSemaphore() on it. And you are missing CloseHandle() on each handle you open. If your goal is to serialize access to the terminal (which is not needed in this example) then a mutex would make more sense than a semaphore.

@Remy Lebeau, Re "you need to actually wait on an open semaphore handle ie with WaitForSingleObject() before you can call ReleaseSemaphore() on it.", That would be odd, and I see nothing about that in the docs for ReleaseSemaphore. Can you support your claim?

@ikegami Semaphore Objects documentation: "Each time one of the wait functions returns because the state of a semaphore was set to signaled, the count of the semaphore is decreased by one. The ReleaseSemaphore function increases a semaphore's count by a specified amount." Opening a semaphore handle doesn't change its counter. Looking at the code again, it shouldn't be using a semaphore at all. It should wait on the threads themselves, by putting their handles into an array and passing that to WaitForMultipleObjects()

@Remy Lebeau, You might very well want to create a semaphore with a count of zero, which you then signal (using ReleaseSemaphore). And this is exactly what the OP is doing. And nothing in that what you just posted says you can't. Your claim is false. One does not need to wait for the semaphore before signaling it.

That said, the OP could simply wait for each the thread handles to become signaled instead of using a semaphore. The semaphore is completely unnecessary.

@ikegami when I posted that initial comment, I didn't see the code was waiting on the semaphore after starting the threads, it looked like it was using the semaphore to serialize the threads. But after seeing the wait, I still stand by my claim that the semaphore is simply the wrong tool for this code in the first place, whether or not the wait+release is being used correctly.

@Remy Lebeau, I agree that a semaphore is suboptimal, but a mutex is worse. See my previous comment for what should be used here. And note that I was commenting on the part of your comment that I quoted, and nothing else. I agree with not giving the semaphore a name here. And I agree that CloseHandle is missing. I only said that your claim that there's a missing WaitForSingleObject() was wrong.

As @Harith answered and your question title said, you already know the lpParameter argument does the trick. But I suspect the function of sem. Your threads just read only on different addresses.

for (i = 0;i < 10;i++) {
    nameOfThread= LETTERS[i];
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, f, &nameOfThread, 0, &name);
}

You're passing the address of nameOfThread to each thread, but as you loop through creating threads, you're overwriting the value of nameOfThread with each iteration.
Changing it to:
CreateThread(NULL, 0, f, &LETTERS[i], 0, &name);

fixes the problem:
$ ./c.exe
I'm a thread: a
I'm a thread: b
I'm a thread: c
I'm a thread: d
I'm a thread: f
I'm a thread: g
I'm a thread: h
I'm a thread: i
I'm a thread: j
I'm a thread: e
I'm the process

And Windows has WaitForMultipleObjects(), you could use that instead of calling WaitForSingleObject() 10 times. And you do not need to cast from a void * to any other pointer type, as there is an implicit conversion to and from a void *.
